# Trying to Stream music while connecting Nexmo NCCO

Tags: php, vonage

I tried to stream music while connecting the agent into the phone call.
but it's stuck in the stream and then calling.

anyone used it before? I'm sure that's impossible to make this.

Code:

```
$array[] = array(
    "action" => "stream",
    "streamUrl" => array("https://pbx.makeapp.co.il/wait.mp3"),
);
$array[] = array(
    "action" => "connect",
    "eventType" => "synchronous",
    "eventUrl" => array("https://pbx.makeapp.co.il/config.json?step=1"),
    "timeout" => 30,
    "from" => "YOUR_NEXMO_PHONE",
    "endpoint" => array(array(
            "type" => "sip",
            "uri" => "sip:your_sip@sip.antisip.com",
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have same issue of playing audio while the call is being transferred.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, it is not possible to have 2 actions running at the same time using an NCCO. When you add a stream action to the start of your NCCO, this must be completed before it moves onto the next action. An NCCO array is actioned from top to bottom, and only moves onto the next action when the current one has finished. You can find out some more info in the concepts of an NCCO section of the documentation: https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/ncco-reference